# DDD Entity identity generation while creation

Tags: java, hibernate, domain-driven-design, entity

I have an enttity in my domain:

```
public final class FieldDefinition {
  private final FieldDefinitionId id;
  private final FieldName name;
  //other fields


  public FieldDefinition(final FieldDefinitionId id,
                         final FieldName name) {
    checkState(id, name, label, type);
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
  }

private void checkState(final FieldDefinitionId id,
                          final FieldName name) {
    Preconditions.checkState(nonNull(id), "id cannot be null");
    Preconditions.checkState(nonNull(name), "name cannot be null");
```

As you can see FieldDefinitionId is required while object creation. This id is generated in database entity:

```
@Entity
public final class FieldDefinitionJpaEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String name;

....
}
```

There 'id' is the same as FieldDefinitionId . It is mapped like that:

```
private FieldDefinition asDomainField(final FieldDefinitionJpaEntity entity) {
    return new FieldDefinition(
            new FieldDefinitionId(entity.getId()),
            new FieldName(entity.getName()),
           // other fields
  }
```

Now i am receiving FieldDefinitionDto from another service which needs to be saved to database. Here is the class

```
class FieldDefinitionDto {
 private final String name;
//other fields
}
```

As you can see there is no id inside DTO object. Now when i am trying to map DTO to domain model i cannot do this because FieldDefinitionId is required. What should i do? Should i create seperate model for creation like FieldDefinitionCreation which is basically the same as FieldDefinition but without FieldDefinitionId ?. I would like to stick to id generation on database level (not on domain level with UUID). Anyone had similar problem? Is keeping 2 seperate models which are almost identical is a good idea?

Comment: From the code you have provided it is not clear how the relation between FieldDefinitionJpaEntity#id and FieldDefinition#id looks like. Provide the code which maps these classes.

Comment: FieldDefinitionJpaEntity#id is the same like FieldDefinition#id . FieldDefinitionId is just a wrapper for long id

Answer (score 1):

Your ID generation strategy simply isn't aligned with your domain model design.

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)` means the identity will be generated by the DB when the entity gets saved. If you choose this strategy then you can't make `id` a required constructor argument in the `FieldDefinition`'s class.

I'm also a bit puzzled why you wouldn't map `FieldDefinition` directly with JPA rather than having `FieldDefinitionJpaEntity`?

Anyway, either you go with an assigned ID upfront (can still be generated in the DB) e.g.

```
FieldDefinitionId id = fieldDefinitionRepository.nextId();
FieldDefinition fd = new FieldDefinition(id, name);
```

or you go with a generated ID upon persisting e.g.

```
FieldDefinition fd = new FieldDefinition(name); //no ID yet
fieldDefinitionRepository.save(fd); //ID assigned
```

I always prefer to generate IDs upfront because it's much easier to generate domain events, among other things.